# Highchart piechart cant get data from database c#

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawPieChart(seriesData) {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Blood Volume'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Brands",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: seriesData
            }]
        });
    }

    $("#btnCreatePieChart").on('click', function (e) {
        var pData = [];
        pData[0] = $('<%=ddlLocation.ClientID%>').val();

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ pData: pData });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/getBloodInventory",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess_,
            error: OnErrorCall_
        });

        function OnSuccess_(response) {
            var aData = response.d;
            var arr = []

            $.map(aData, function (item, index) {
                var i = [item.id, item.volume];
                var obj = {};
                obj.name = item.id;
                obj.y = item.volume;
                arr.push(obj);
            });
            var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
            var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));

            drawPieChart(jsonArray);

        }
        function OnErrorCall_(response) {
            alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });


</script>
```

[WebMethod]

```
    public List<bloodInventory> getBloodInventory(List<string> pData)
    {
        List<bloodInventory> p = new List<bloodInventory>();


        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            string myQuery = "select blood_group_id,SUM(volume) as volume from BloodInventory b, Donors d where (b.donor_id = d.donor_id and blood_bank_id=@blood_bank_id)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = myQuery;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blood_bank_id", pData[0]);
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    bloodInventory cpData = new bloodInventory();
                    cpData.id = dr["blood_group_id"].ToString();
                    cpData.volume = Convert.ToInt32(dr["volume"].ToString());
                    p.Add(cpData);
                }
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
```

Above is my code where i want to display a piechart based on selection from dropdown list. When i click the button to show it shows that error 404 which the url not found, can i know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you please show me the request log from your browser? Coz it might be a real 404 error, may be you are not requesting to a correct URL

Comment: http://localhost:1890/WebForm1.aspx/getBloodInventory

Comment: Sory not the URL! Open developer tools on your browser and go to the Network tab! And try to view your chart, and you'll see the the request information to help you / us debug what is really happening!

Comment: On preview tab there show Unknown web method getBloodInventory.

Comment: Ok, i solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: has you can see the problem here is with you server side and not your Ajax request or hichart itself! So unfortunately I'm not an C# expert! Good luck